# What is a .json file used for in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, crud

What exactly is a .json file used for in a professional rails app?

I created a scaffold for my Blog and understand the CRUD actions with with postgresql DB, however I am just wondering about the `format.json` lines of code that are also created in a scaffold.

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @blog.save
      format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is a commonly used format for API's, and commonly used in Rails API's.

When you're doing `format.json` in the controllers, you're really saying "This route/endpoint can respond to JSON requests", and not only html requests.

When a website is viewed in a browser, your browser automatically sends along a HTTP Header called `Accept`. Such as:

```
Accept: <MIME_type>/<MIME_subtype>
Accept: <MIME_type>/*
Accept: */*
```

This may be any number of MIME-Types; Including `Accept: application/json`, which will tell Rails, that it may respond with JSON.

What the browser does, is to send along `Accept: text/html`, which is perceived as "Hi, I want the HTML edition of this", thus rendering the `format.html`-block.

*See also:*

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Comment: Rails also lets you set the format by extension. So for example `/blogs/1.json` will request the JSON format. I think this actually overrides the headers as well.

Comment: @max Very true! As far as I remember, the chain of priority is (highest to lowest): "Manual override (route format; also eliminating all other options, essentially); extension; Accept-types; "default" (eg `:defaults => { format: 'json' }` in routes"

Any possibly some other secret ways of defining response-types, that aren't used often, and/or not documented much.